# "Me and Joey's" or "mine and Joey's"

Tags: possessives

Which of the following should I use?

> Today is me and Joey's anniversary
>   Today is mine and Joey's anniversary

Comment: Neither. _Today is my anniversary, today is Joey's anniversary_ => _Today is my and Joey's anniversary_

Comment: If you are saying that both you and Joey have anniversaries today, @mplungjan’s comment is correct. If you are saying that you an Joey are together and this is your anniversary as a couple, you can treat ‘me and Joey’ as a single noun phrase, in which case “me and Joey’s” is fine.

Comment: Ah, I did not even read that they might be a couple. Silly me. _Today Joey and I are celebrating OUR anniversary_ is less ambiguous

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "'me and Joey’s' is fine."?? Surely not? Sounds very odd in BrE.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes - it said *anniversary* - not *birthday*! (But I also mis-read it at first - but I did realise before reading JBJ's comment!) :-)

Answer (score 10):

First, I would put the other person first. So the sentence should begin, "Today is Joey's and..."

To finish the sentence, "Today is Joey's and **my** anniversary."

As a test, take away "Joey's and." Then you get: "Today is my (not mine) anniversary.

Comment: Is the reason why you want to put the other person first a grammatical reason or a politeness reason? _Joey's and my_ does sound better than _My and Joey's_ does, but I'm not sure whether that's due to the strange isolation of _my_ from what it modifies, since _My and Joey's_ doesn't sound ungrammatical per se.

Comment: @JohnLawler: It's a "politeness" issue. Other person first. Especially if s/he is your spouse.

Comment: Cool. I agree completely; but it's important to note that it's not a grammar issue. "Grammar" already covers too much territory here.

Comment: As a guideline (not a rule; just a guideline), put third person first, second person next, and first person last. E.g., "Today we celebrate Joey's, your and my anniversaries."

Comment: As a rule (not a guideline) always put your spouse first. It might not always be grammatical but it is always a safer bet.

Answer (score 2):

I guess:

"Today is Joey's anniversary and mine."

should also work.

Comment: -1 That does not recognise that they are a *couple*. It's presumably the anniversary of them becoming a couple.

Comment: Actually i did not interpret the original as a couple. I thought of 2 distinct anniversaries.  :-)

Comment: For a couple, I would imagine one just uses: "Today is our anniversary", and not use such a complicate wording.

Comment: The question didn't necessarily specify a couple, and "Today is our anniversary" only works if the two people are present when it is said or with some added context

Comment: Well I almost agree. Except that the reference to the partner can be implicit (maybe because referenced before in a discourse). She need not be physically present (at least we can use it that way in my country, not sure elsewhere).

Comment: @TsSkTo The question actually specified *two* people & *one* anniversary (singular). We don't know that *both* people were present: I assume they weren't, otherwise she *would* have said "our anniversary". As she referred to her & *Joey's* anniversary, I assume she was talking to a friend,  and Joey was *not* present.