# Order: "Yours and Derricks" or "Derrick and yours"?

Tags: compounds, direct-objects

I am thanking 2 people for their help. Do I say

- Yours and Dericks support
  or
- Derrick and your support

Which is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the grammatically correct way of attributing possession to "her and others’ lives"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/568242/what-is-the-grammatically-correct-way-of-attributing-possession-to-the-noun-phra/568273#568273)  Or [My and Linda's or Mine and Linda's?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162590/my-and-lindas-or-mine-and-lindas)? Or [Me and Joey's or mine and Joey's?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125283/me-and-joeys-or-mine-and-joeys)?

Comment: Essentially, the possessive determiner (appearing before the noun _support_) must be _your_ not _yours_ (though _Derick's support and yours_ works for non-combined support; here, _yours_ is a pronoun).  The possessive structure (_Derrick's_) is needed **if the support is seen as individual rather than combined**. // The order is optional (_Your and Derick's support / Derick's  and your support_. // _John and Derick's support_ would be used for 'joint possession treated as combined rather than individual', but I don't find _Derrick and your support_ very natural.

Comment: See [Nikki's and Alice's cars vs Nikki and Alice's cars](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x) for discussion of "segregatory" (or "distributive") possession vs "combinatorial" (or "joint") (co-owned) possession, including  the acceptability of "you and your wife's bank account").

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I don't think the question with two proper nouns (Nikki and Alice) is very relevant to the OP's situation. They cannot switch "your/s" with the actual name of the person, the thank you is directed to a friend (you) and presumably a second friend, or to their partner or husband. The OP could say “**I want to thank** ***you and Derrick*** **for all your support**” but the question wasn't about rephrasing.  *Aimè* there are many ways to skin a cat, so they say.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A
 The answer given by gpr is. And the useful extension is in line with the spirit of ELU: well-collated reasonably easily searched information about reasonably scoped topics.

Answer (score 1):

REVISION
I had originally suggested that "Yours and Derrick's support" was acceptable, and I still think it is, especially in speech but a commentator corrected me

> ... Yours support? "Derrick's support and yours" is fine, where 'yours' **following** *Derrick's support* is acceptable for 'your support'

So it's my time to eat humble pie; for formal situations and in writing "Your support and Derrick's“ is grammatically correct.

---

**Amended**

It's either "Your support and **Derrick's**” OR "**Derrick's** and your support”

In which order you place these terms is personal preference; it does not depend on grammar.

But don't forget the possessive apostrophe in Derrick's to show ownership. The possessive determiner *your* already implies ownership.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  "Yours support" is clearly unacceptable, where did I suggest it wasn't? Humbug, it's English, people say these things all the time. The orthographical error lies in the missing apostrophe.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well it could *also* be "**Yours and Derrick's**"  adding "*support*" clarifies what is being discussed but I have amended my answer. Hope that appeases your sense of propriety.